# In Google Cloud Datastore, how can I check if a write operation failed?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using GAE for PHP, but I don't think that the language matters. I'm trying to use `transactions`, but the same thing would apply to any regular datastore 
 batch operations (like `insert`, `update`, or `upsert`).

I don't see any way to check the result of those operations. They appear to return the `version` of the entity, but how do I know if one of the operations in a batch failed (for any reason)?

Thanks

Comment: How are you checking the results? In [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) states that Datastore will return an error if the operations that you described fail.